# Is there an existing dashboard with sonar and TFS builds

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, sonarqube, dashboard

I would like to know if an existing solution is already existing in order to display a visual dashboard with an aggregation of info coming from MS team server foundation (builds status) and SonarQube analysis..

I know I can do it by myself by consuming the API from the two but I would like to not reinventing the wheel..

I tried to google it but I'm not finding anything. Does someone already using something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a product manager at SonarSource, I'm not aware of such kind of tool/dashboard.